# How to plot Series with selective ticks?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a `Series` that I would like to plot as a bar chart: `pd.Series([-4,2, 3,3, 4,5,9,20]).value_counts()`
Since I have many bars I only want to display some (equidistant) ticks.
However, unless I actively work against it, pyplot will print the wrong labels. E.g. if I leave out `set_xticklabels` in the code below I get 
[image: wrong labels]
where every element from the index is taken and just displayed with the specified distance.

This code does what I want:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
s = pd.Series([-4,2, 3,3, 4,5,9,20]).value_counts().sort_index()  
mi,ma = min(s.index), max(s.index)  
s = s.reindex(range(mi,ma+1,1), fill_value=0)  
distance = 10 
a = s.plot(kind='bar') 
condition = lambda t: int(t[1].get_text()) % 10 == 0 
ticks_,labels_=zip(*filter(condition, zip(a.get_xticks(), a.get_xticklabels())))  
a.set_xticks(ticks_)   
a.set_xticklabels(labels_) 
plt.show()
```

[image: correct labels]

But I still feel like I'm being unnecessarily clever here. Am I missing a function? Is this the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider not using a pandas bar plot in case you intend to plot numeric values; that is because pandas bar plots are categorical in nature.

If instead using a matplotlib bar plot, which is numeric in nature, there is no need to tinker with any ticks at all.

```
s = pd.Series([-4,2, 3,3, 4,5,9,20]).value_counts().sort_index()
plt.bar(s.index, s)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you overcomplicated it. You can simply use the following. You just need to find the relationship between the ticks and the ticklabels.

```
a = s.plot(kind='bar') 

xticks = np.arange(0, max(s)*10+1, 10) 
plt.xticks(xticks + abs(mi), xticks)
```

[image]